# What format do my keys need to be in to use Node.js Crypto module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pem

I have a set(s) of public/private keys that I would like to use to digitally sign some messages.  The keys are created by, and used on, a blockchain.  They are in string format.  Here's one of the public keys: `STM7udfcW7tcVqfiVhkcK3rtXsBw8zdyii7Gh7oXuNfHf3jxnVwg3`. I've been informed that the STM prefix isn't part of the key.  Node.js crypto module allows you to sign and verify messages using public/private keys.  Here's a sample script:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

/*const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
  namedCurve: 'sect239k1'
});

console.log(privateKey);
console.log(JSON.stringify(privateKey);*/

const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
sign.write('some data to sign');
sign.end();
const signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'hex');

const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
verify.write('some data to sign');
verify.end();
console.log(verify.verify(publicKey, signature, 'hex'));
// Prints: true
```

Using the blockchain keys as strings leads to an error:

```
const ret = this[kHandle].sign(data, format, type, passphrase, rsaPadding,
                            ^

Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:105:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\signature\index.js:14:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  library: 'PEM routines',
  function: 'get_name',
  reason: 'no start line',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'
```

This might suggest that the keys need to be in "PEM" format?  I'm not sure how to get them in that format.  Using the script to create new keys and referring to the console logs, I can see that the Crypto module creates the keys as an object (`PrivateKeyObject { [Symbol(kKeyType)]: 'private' }`), not a string, but when I stringify that it comes out as an empty object.  So I'm kind of lost as to how to convert my string keys into the correct format.

I did try some code I found online that supposedly converts to PEM, but it didn't work. The code is:

```
function arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    var byteString = '';
    for(var i=0; i < byteArray.byteLength; i++) {
        byteString += String.fromCharCode(byteArray[i]);
    }
    var buffer = new Buffer(byteString);
    var b64 = buffer.toString("base64");

    console.log("b64:",b64)
    return b64;
}

function addNewLines(str) {
    var finalString = '';
    while(str.length > 0) {
        finalString += str.substring(0, 64) + '\n';
        str = str.substring(64);
    }

    return finalString;
}

function toPem(privateKey) {
    var b64 = addNewLines(arrayBufferToBase64(privateKey));
    var pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + b64 + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
    
    return pem;
}

function toPem2(publicKey) {
    var b64 = addNewLines(arrayBufferToBase64(publicKey));
    var pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" + b64 + "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    
    return pem;
}
```

The error is because `addNewLines()` returns an empty string.  Presumably because `arrayBufferToBase64()` expects an array, not a string as its parameter.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your private key header/footer is wrong

use this instead

```
function toPem(privateKey) {
    var b64 = addNewLines(arrayBufferToBase64(privateKey));
    var pem = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + b64 + "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    
    return pem;
}
```